# Drawing border to specific country in google map incorrect

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantnawarkhede/4PANk/) , I want to draw border for county India,

For displaying border to specific country i am modifying layer object to ,

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {select: "kml_4326", 
          from: tableid,
          where: "sovereignt = 'India'"},
  styles: [{
  polygonOptions: {
    strokeWeight: "10",
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: "0.11",
    fillOpacity: "0.0",
    fillColor: "#000000"
  }
}]});
```

When i give `"sovereignt = 'India'"` it is not applying border to India . But if i used any country name other than India it is working correct. ( I have tested for china, pakistan,Australia,Iraq,Iran)

Why it is not applying border to India ? Whats wrong i am doing here ?

Comment: It is drawing border just for east coast and for Andaman and Nicobar islands.

Comment: @AntoJurković Yes. But why it is not drawing border for India ? Any reason ?

Comment: Don't know. Similar with Denmark and Greenland. Some parts are marked some not. There is straight cut off like another part of map should be used.

Comment: Impossible to answer this without knowing the contents of this table. But obviously(see **http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/LnddC/**) the data in this table are not complete(I better say: doesn't fit your needs, because I'm not sure for what these data have been created for)

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks. Can you please explain in the example fiddle why India , Brazi and canada are not marked ? I didnt see any query in this example. What if i want to just whole county except India ?

Comment: As I said, impossible to answer without knowing the data of the table, but as it seems the table doesn't contain data for these areas(or the data is corrupt). Without any query you will get all data. To exclude a country you must use a NOT IN condition in the where-clause , e.g. [`"sovereignt NOT IN('China')"`](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/LnddC/2/)

Comment: [This table and query](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=India) work for me (from the Natural Earth Data set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with the data for the countries you are having issues with in the table you are using ([419167](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S1273110kswB))

This table works fine: [420419](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S1273111oSQ9) (also from the Natural Earth Data set)

Example ([working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PANk/7/))

```
var layer; // Fusion Tables layer
var tableid = 420419;

layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {select: "kml_4326", 
          from: tableid,
          where: "name_0 = 'India'"},
  styles: [{
  polygonOptions: {
    strokeWeight: "2",
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: "0.4",
    fillOpacity: "0.0",
    fillColor: "#000000"
  }
}]});

layer.setMap(map);
```

[Analyzing the KML in the kml_4236 column for India](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_winding_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_FusionTables_India.kml), it looks "OK", one of the Polygons is strange (looks like it only contains two unique coordinates), hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks ,can i show borders for that country only ? It is also currently showing borders for all states. And how can i disable popup of information when user clicks on borders ?